# Can't fire UILocalNotification on custom time ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to fire NSLocalNotification on my custom time. Ex. 1hour before
 appointment time but unable to set it on my custom time.

```
NSDate *dt1 = [NSDate date]; //2018-07-18 10:41:22 +0000

NSString *datestr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];//2018-07-18 10:42:09 +0000

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(11,5);

NSString *cutstring = 05:00 PM;
```

By this I add substring to current date and change date in my custom
 date.

```
NSString *newstr = [cutstring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];

NSString *changed = [datestr stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:newstr]; //2018-07-18 05:00:09 +0000
```

By this code I got my custom time '2018-07-18 05:00:09 +0000' on which I want to fire UILocalNotification, But issue is that when I set my custom time with NSLocalNotification it set's on such a random time like **18 July 2018 at 4:19:29 PM**

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
    NSDate *fireddate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:changed];
    localNotification.fireDate = fireddate;
    NSLog(@"%@",fireddate);
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have appointment in 1 hour"];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotification.category = @"ACTIONABLE";
```

---

```
 //Received Local Notification:<UIConcreteLocalNotification:
 0x6000003887b0>{fire date = Wednesday, 18 July 2018 at 4:19:29 PM
 India Standard Time, time zone = (null), repeat interval = 0, repeat
 count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date =
 (null), user info = { }}
```

Comment: It is silly to form a date from a string with an NSDateFormatter. You need a date; form the NSDate, directly.

Comment: what does "now" mean in your code ?

Comment: Yes @matt , I have only time of todays appointment like '4:00 PM' and I have to convert it into full date format as I need all date.

Comment: now stands for current date @NisarAhmad

Comment: "I have only time of todays appointment like '4:00 PM' and I have to convert it into full date" Fine, but passing it through a string is not how you do that. You need to learn how to form an NSDate. For example you could use NSDateComponents to form this NSDate.

Comment: I tried it too, but than I stuck into assembling components into date & am pm issue . . . I choose passing date through string cause it returns me perfect date format in string. . . . Can you please give me idea, How to do it in right way?? @matt

Comment: Forming NSDate correctly has been explained many times here. What I'm saying is that your question likely has nothing to do with firing a notification or forming a local notification, but with how to make a date. You need to start by debugging and seeing where the _real_ problem is. Then you can either solve that problem or ask about it.

Comment: I have perfect date in string format but converting it into date and using it into localnotification.fired causes a problem. 
Ex: I have date '2018-07-18 05:00:09 +0000' but after converting it into date & used the notification sets @4:19:29 PM that is not my date in string format containts.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a fire date with `NSDateComponents` where you can set `year`, `month`, `hour`, `minute` etc.

Something like this:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[dateComponents setYear:year];
[dateComponents setMonth:month];
[dateComponents setDay:day];
[dateComponents setHour:hour];

NSDate *fireDate = [dateComponents date];
```

You can read more about it in this great article

[NSDate​Components - NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/)